# How to export a text file from SQLite3 with CLI Kubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line, kubuntu

Unsure if it is even possible to get a human friendly text file from this SQLite3 file with CLI (Command Line Interface) Terminal with Kubuntu.

using:

```
neofetch --stdout |grep 'OS:'
```

OS: Kubuntu 22.04.3 LTS x86_64

```
sqlite -version
```

2.8.17

---

**Specifics**: Names of God (NOG) Bible 2011 `https://www.ph4.org/b4_index.php` `NOG.zip` (2.0 MiB; 2,069,114
bytes and extracts to `NOG.SQLite3` (5.6 MiB; 5,832,704 bytes)

command1:

```
sqlite /home/xx/Downloads/NOG/NOG.SQLite3 /home/xx/Downloads/NOG
```

```
Unable to open database 
"/home/xx/Downloads/NOG/NOG.SQLite3": 
file is encrypted or is not a database
```

command2:

```
sqlite3 -header -csv ./home/xx/Downloads/NOG/NOG.SQLite3 "select * from eS1100_sensor_results;" >./out.csv
```

```
Error: unable to open database 
"./home/xx/Downloads/NOG/NOG.SQLite3": 
unable to open database file
```

Is it even possible to export from `NOG.SQLite3`?

If yes then how to export a friendly text file from `NOG.SQLite3`?

`NOG.SQLite3` (5.6 MiB; 5,832,704) bytes

Comment: Have you tried opening the database with a graphical browser such as `/usr/bin/sqlitebrowser` ?

Comment: Also what is the output of the command `file /home/xx/Downloads/NOG/NOG.SQLite3` ?

Comment: ```file /home/xx/Downloads/NOG/NOG.SQLite3``` 
/home/xx/Downloads/NOG/NOG.SQLite3: 
```SQLite 3.x database, ```
last written using SQLite version 3008009, 
```page size 32768, ```
file counter 250, 
```database pages 178, ```
cookie 0x89, 
```schema 4, ```
UTF-8, 
```version-valid-for 250```

Comment: ```sudo snap install sqlitebrowser```  

sqlitebrowser --version
```Qt: Session management error: Could not open network socket``` 
DB Browser for SQLite Version 3.12.99 (May 24 2021)

```Built for x86_64-little_endian-lp64, running on x86_64```
Qt Version 5.5.1
```SQLCipher Version 4.4.3 community (based on SQLite 3.34.1).```

Comment: You can install sqlitebrowser with `sudo apt install sqlitebrowser` You don't need snap for this.

Comment: A distinction was made between ```snap``` and ```apt``` example:  
```sudo snap install sqlitebrowser```  and 
```sudo apt  install sqlitebrowser```.  
What is the difference?  
What is the difference between ```snap``` and ```apt``` 
as it applies to the program 
sqlitebrowser ```Version 3.12.99``` (May 24 2021) ?

Comment: I don't understand the error that the snap package manager sent you when you tried to install sqlitebrowser. I think installing with apt instead of snap should guarantee a correct integration of the program in your Kubuntu 22.04 graphical environment.